# Extrair informações do cabeçalho de requests no Fiddler

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, telerik

Estou precisando extrair informações do cabeçalho de uma *request* no aplicativo `FIDDLER` para fazer uma comparação de uma variável de contexto que é enviada no cabeçalho e setar rotas baseado nessa variável.

No caso, se a variável for valor 3, o `fiddler` deve chamar uma rota, se for 2 , deve chamar outra rota!!!

Alguma ideia de como fazer isso?
lembrando que, a variável vem no cabeçalho da *request*, e não na `url/uri`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não sei se eu entendi muito bem, mas se quer recuperar o valor do `Header` da requisição, basta fazer o seguinte:

```
    var teste = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["Content-Type"];
```

Onde `Headers["Content-Type"]` é a variável que deseja recuperar.